# Sao for tryton 4.6 and gnuhealth

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile, webclient, tryton

I have managed to install tryton and gnuhealth in a docker container with a docker file.

After installing the web client sao I am able to log in but i get a repeating notification popup `Calling method resources on  is not allowed`
it keeps popping up making the usage of the web client impossible.
Initially the popup message was `Forbidden` but i solved this by moving the postgres attach folder into the gnuhealth user space.

The message is get from debug console in the browser is 
`POST http://localhost:8000/health/bus 404 NOT FOUND`

Is there a specific version of sao that i need to install for it to work 
I have used sao from both
`git clone https://github.com/tryton/sao.git`
and
`hg clone http://hg.tryton.org/sao`

I am following https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation
The only difference is that i am using dockerfile and docker-compose

I am not sure what the problem is.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x  | bash -

RUN apt-get -y install sudo \
       nano \
       gcc \
       g++ \
       patch \
       vim

RUN adduser gnuhealth && \
    echo "gnuhealth ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/gnuhealth && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/gnuhealth

USER gnuhealth
RUN sudo apt-get install nodejs
ENV PATH="/home/gnuhealth/.local/bin:/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-4.6.19/bin:${PATH}"
WORKDIR home/gnuhealth

RUN wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/health/gnuhealth-latest.tar.gz
RUN wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/health/gnuhealth-3.4.1.tar.gz.sig
RUN tar xzf gnuhealth-latest.tar.gz

WORKDIR ./gnuhealth-3.4.1

RUN wget -qO- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/health/gnuhealth-setup-latest.tar.gz | tar -xzvf -
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
RUN ./gnuhealth-setup install

RUN echo '[database] \n\
uri = postgresql://database:5432 \n\
path = /home/gnuhealth/attach \n\
\n\
[web] \n\
listen = *:8000 \n\
root=/home/gnuhealth/sao \n\
\n\
[webdav] \n\
listen = *:8080 \n\
ssl_webdav = False\n' > ~/gnuhealth/tryton/server/config/trytond.conf

WORKDIR /home/gnuhealth
RUN hg clone http://hg.tryton.org/sao sao
WORKDIR ./sao
RUN sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN npm install grunt --save-dev
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm audit fix
RUN grunt
```

Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  gnuserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
     - database

    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGHOST=database
      - PGPORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - database
    command: ./start_gnuhealth.sh

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Health 3.4 uses Tryton 4.6 series. So you must also use the series 4.6 of sao. You can find it under the name `tryton-sao`: https://downloads-cdn.tryton.org/4.6/

But another easier way to setup GNU Health on Docker would be to use the Tryton docker image `tryton/tryton:4.6` an install the GNU Health packages using `pip`. This image contains the trytond server and the right sao.

Comment: I get the same error even if i pull the tryton/tryton;4.6 image

Comment: I guess you did not correctly get the 4.6 series or the webpage was not correctly refreshed because series 4.6 does not have any 'bus' reference (added only in 5.0).

Comment: True. i stopped getting the error when i changed this line `RUN hg clone http://hg.tryton.org/sao sao` to `RUN hg clone http://hg.tryton.org/sao -r 4.6.20 sao`

Comment: I am looking at your second suggestion. I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703236/starting-tryton-server-with-docker-compose-file)

Comment: If you want to always have the last commit from series 4.6, you can run: `hg clone -b 4.6 https://hg.tryton.org/sao`