# Starting Tryton server with docker-compose file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, tryton

I am trying to link an external postgres to tryton/tryton from docker hub.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  tryton-postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=tryton
    restart: always

  gnuserver:
    image: tryton/tryton:4.6
    links:
      - tryton-postgres:postgres
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - tryton-postgres
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh trytond
```

when i ssh into the container and run `trytond-admin --all -d tryton` it seems to be looking for sqlite file instead of the connected postgres database. Are there some env variagbles i must set? What am i missing in my docker compose file?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the configuration file, with Docker it is simpler to set environment variable like:

```
DB_USER=
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_HOSTNAME=tryton-postgres
DB_PORT=5432
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit `/etc/tryton/trytond.conf` to look at `postgresql`:

```
uri = postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@tryton-postgres:5432/
```

see the [Docs](https://blog.lordvan.com/blog/tryton-setup-config/)